How to prevent update call in nested RealityViews
I have two Views First and Second which contains RealityView. Second is used as attachments in First. And I have @State in First. After changing this state, SwiftUI also call the update block on the Second view (this state is not used in the second view).
How to prevent unnecessary calls to update blocks in Second ?
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct First: View {

    @State private var isButtonTapped = false

    var body: some View {
        print("Body #1")
        return VStack {
            RealityView { content, attach in
                let model = sphereModel(y: 0, color: .brown)
                content.add(model)
            } update: { content, attach in
                print(isButtonTapped)
                print("Update #1")
                guard let someView = attach.entity(for: "id")
                else { return }
                content.add(someView)
            } attachments: {
                Attachment(id: "id") {
                    Second()
                }
            }

            Button("BUTTON") { isButtonTapped.toggle() }
        }
    }
}

struct Second: View {

    var body: some View {
        print("Body #2")

        return RealityView { content in
            let model = sphereModel(y: 0, color: .red)
            content.add(model)
        } update: { content in
            print("Update #2")
        }
    }
}

func sphereModel(y: Float, color: UIColor) -> ModelEntity {
    let collisionComponent = CollisionComponent(
        shapes: [ShapeResource.generateSphere(radius: 0.01)]
    )

    let hoverEffectComponent = HoverEffectComponent(.highlight(.init(color: .blue)))

    var sphereModelMaterial = PhysicallyBasedMaterial()
    sphereModelMaterial.baseColor = .init(tint: color)

    let sphereMesh = MeshResource.generateSphere(radius: 0.01)

    let sphereModel = ModelEntity(
        mesh: sphereMesh,
        materials: [sphereModelMaterial]
    )

    sphereModel.transform.translation = .init(x: 0, y: y, z: 0)
    sphereModel.components.set(
        [
            collisionComponent,
            hoverEffectComponent
        ]
    )

    return sphereModel
}

